# cakephp prevent user login from multiple locations at the same time

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a CakePHP 1.3.10 website with a login system using Auth. How can I prevent a same username/password to log in at the same time from different locations? It should work in a way that when an already logged in user logs from a different location, the first one gets kicked out (so the last one can keep using my website).

I've been doing some research and I can't find a "good enough" solution. It seems that a simple one would be storing a boolean to 1 when a user logs in, but I don't know what to do with that to make this work the way I describe.

The easy part is that when the user logs out, I change that value to 0. But what if he just closes the browser? And what do I do when a user logs in and the boolean is already set to 1? How do I kick to "old" user?

Any advice would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that, change your config/core.php to use database-driven sessions.

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
```

After that, also uncomment the following line:

```
//Configure::write('Session.database', 'default');
```

Using the default DB config is what you'll want in most cases.

Then, prepare your database for hosting the sessions by using the Cake console:

```
cake schema create Sessions
```

Finally, in your login action, check if a session already exists for the user that just logged in and invalidate/delete their old session from the sessions table.

I haven't used this method myself before, but I figure the user id/username is stored in the `data` field of the sessions table (which probably holds a serialized array or something like that).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have a question: running that command from the Cake console will create a table in the DB? If so, how can I choose in what DB will be created (in my web I'm using 2 different DBs)?

Comment: @Albert That's what you need to set the `Session.database` value to in your core config. Whatever you set there should be used for creating the table. Alternatively you could just "read" the schema file and create the table manually, when in doubt.

Comment: OK, I have the database sessions working now. I log in and I can see a new entry in the DB sessions table. It has an **id** field (I assume it's the session value), a **data** field (has a serialized array with the session and the user's info) and a **expires** field with a 11 digit number. How can I check if a session already exists for the user that just logged in? If it exists, do I just **delete()** that row and Cake will create a new row with the new session info?