# CakePHP Check Session exists in database

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Im Using [CakePHP 2.2.1](http://cakephp.org/) and im trying to improve my User Authentication with the [Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).  When Users try to log in from multiple locations they get individual session IDs, what i want to do is kill the old session so the user cannot log in from multiple locations at the same time.

I converted how CakePHP saves its sessions using this post [cakephp prevent user login from multiple locations at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669858/cakephp-prevent-user-login-from-multiple-locations-at-the-same-time) but no answer was given on how to kill off the old session when the new one is created.

I thought about creating a Session Model and using that to select the records but im not sure if thats a safe route to go with.

I also read through the CakePHP documentation on the [Session Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html) and CakeSession Datasource hoping there might be a hint but i wasnt able to find anything.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you want to switch Session handling to Database, so you can delete stale sessions when you detect the same user logs in with a different `session_id`.

The steps, to give you an idea:

1. Switch Session handling to Database

   ```
   Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
   ```
2. Create `cake_sessions` table

   ```
   cd app         
   Console/cake schema create Sessions
   ```

   You would then see the following:

   ```
   Cake Schema Shell
   ---------------------------------------------------------------

   The following table(s) will be dropped.
   cake_sessions
   Are you sure you want to drop the table(s)? (y/n) 
   [n] > y
   Dropping table(s).
   cake_sessions updated.

   The following table(s) will be created.
   cake_sessions
   Are you sure you want to create the table(s)? (y/n) 
   [y] > y
   Creating table(s).
   cake_sessions updated.
   End create.
   ```
3. Assuming you bind `session_id` to `user_id` by

   ```
   $this->Session->write('user_id', 123456);
   ```
4. Iterate through `data` field at your session database and delete the row off if the same `user_id` enters your site and with a different `session_id`.

   Unfortunately, CakePHP stores `data` as `serialize()`-ed data. You will have to either iterate through each of the rows at `cake_sessions` table to look for matching `user_id` contained in seralized `data` to delete.

   Or, just to give you an idea, you can use the following SQL for an *approximate* method to delete the associated row:

   ```
   DELETE FROM `cake_sessions` WHERE `cake_sessions`.`data` LIKE '%123456%';
   ```
5. That way the old user who has the old `session_id` will not be able to continue on the site as the logged in user.

Comment: So basically there is no way i can detect a User Session with CakePHPs default SessionComponent or AuthComponent?  Like I said above im already at a point where the sessions are being written into the database, im just trying to access the records before Authenticating a User and wasnt sure if CakePHP supported this or if i would have to do manually as you pointed out with the DELETE query.

Comment: You have to do it manually. CakePHP doesn't support this feature "out of the box".

Answer (score 3):

The other way to do this would be to create a session_id field in your user table, and use this to store the users current session id after they login.

On each page if the session_id doesn't equal the current session_id then delete all session data and redirect them to the login page as it must either be old session data or a concurrent session.

Note: After verifying that the session in the user table is the current session, when regenerating the session id also remember to update the session_id field in the user table, or every time the session regenerates the user will be logged out.

Comment: I think Uzyns solution fits my project a little better but i prefer this solution.  This is much cleaner and more simple, without the use of an "ugly" query looking for data with LIKE.  thanks